# Spring, Thyme: redirecting to <select> value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a small problem, I just need to redirect to the value of select like:

**/results/name/Heli Redel**

How would I go about doing that?

```
<div class="search">
        <select th:required="true">
            <option th:value="'Eha Raudreha'" th:text="'Eha Raudreha'"></option>
            <option th:value="'Heli Redel'" th:text="'Heli Redel'"></option>
            <option th:value="'Mait Kuusevaik'" th:text="'Mait Kuusevaik'"></option>
        </select>
        <a class="buttons" th:href="@{|/results/name/NAME_HERE|}"><button class="deleteBtn">Otsi</button></a><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a jQuery function, that when the button is clicked, it redirects to a another url.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.deleteBtn').on('click', function() {
        var selectValue = $('.search').find('select').val()
        window.location.replace("/result/name/" + selectValue);
    })

})
```

I would add some ids to your elements to make it easier to fetch data.